# Ethernet connection unmanaged

Tags: ethernet, connectivity

I am using elementaryOS 5.1.7 Hera and I suddenly don't have any ethernet connection. Network manager says it's unmanaged. I checked that `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` has indeed `managed=true`. Also the command `ifconfig` only displays the connection `lo` and `wlp2s0` and I don't have any `eth0`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2901/unmanaged-network-icon-network-manangement-disabled) that worked for me:

`sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf`

`sudo service network-manager restart`